# Use app server certificate for sub domains

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I have a bought a azure app service certificate for my root domain.  Can I use the same certificate for my sub domains?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of certificate you create, a **standard certificate** or a **wildcard certificate**. If you select **standard**, you get a certificate that secures both the root domain and the `www` subdomain.  If you select **wildcard** you get all subdomains.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site